# How to fetch the YouTube categories list through API?

Tags: php, laravel, youtube-api

I'm trying to find something in the YouTube API that will allow me to fetch all YouTube categories. In addition I'm using Laravel and aim for integrating the retrieved data in that context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the sollution we will get the youtube categories list through below google api

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videoCategories?key={your public access api key here}&part=snippet&regionCode=IN
```

key => Your public access api key.

regionCode =>It  is an ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 country code.